# Convert a date string in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a date string as '15-Feb-2030'.
How can I change this to something like 2030-02-15 ??

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Cheers
Shanka

Comment: Please take a few moments and search the site (as well as Google) before posting a question.

Comment: Use: `SELECT TO_DATE('15-FEB-2030', 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM dual;`